# Cocoa - Capturing NSStatusItem mouse hover event

Tags: cocoa, events, mouse, nsstatusitem

How do I execute a function when a user's mouse hovers over my NSStatusItem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you assign a custom `NSView` to your `NSStatusItem`'s `view` property, you can override the `NSResponder` methods `mouseEntered:`, `mouseMoved:` and `mouseExited:`.

Comment: It's the only sensible way. A regular `NSStatusItem` only supports a menu or target-action for when it's clicked.

Comment: How about adding an NSTrackingArea to the WebView? Would that not work?